# Unrecognized selector error when I tap a button

Tags: ios, swift, unrecognized-selector

I'm having some problem with my app. The message Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT keeps popping up when I press a `UIButton`.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var instructions: UILabel!


@IBOutlet var lockStatus: UIImageView!

@IBAction func hackButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)


        while(timer == 1){instructions.text = "loading"}
        while(timer == 2){instructions.text = "loading."}
    while(timer == 3) {instructions.text = "loading.."}
        while(timer == 4){instructions.text = "loading..."}
        while(timer == 5) {instructions.text = "hack successful!"
            lockStatus.image = UIImage(named: "unlocked.png")
            timer.invalidate()

    }

    }



override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

I checked the debugger, and it keeps saying that I sent an unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa7baebc4c0. Can someone help me figure out what this means?

Comment: None of those `while` loops will ever run.

Comment: And should they ever run, they will never stop running :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a method called "update" when you create your timer but your code (at least the portion you shared) does NOT have an update function.

```
@IBAction func hackButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

func update() {   // do your updates here 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `timer == 1` doesn't mean anything. The function update will be called by the timer and from there you can yourself keep a counter and increment it.

Comment: The reason for the crash is the missing `update` function, but this is an important point as well.